# QStackedWidget opening multiple windows

Tags: python, pyqt

I have build a small application using PyQt and as far as I know QStackedWidget is used for making multipage applications. The issue is that it is opening multiple pages and also I'm unable to redirect to `class Xyz` using button in `class Abc`.

main.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.stacked_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        widget_1 = Abc(self.stacked_widget)
        widget_2 = Xyz(self.stacked_widget)

        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(widget_1)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(widget_2)

        self.showMaximized()

class Abc(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, stacked_widget, parent=None):
        super(Abc, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.stacked_widget = stacked_widget

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.frame_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Click me!')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.frame_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.frame_layout)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.showMaximized()

    def click(self):
        print("You clicked me!")
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1)

class Xyz(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Xyz, self).__init__(parent)

        self.frame_layout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()
        self.page1 = Page("Page 1", self.frame_layout)
        self.page2 = Page("Page 2", self.frame_layout)
        self.frame_layout.addWidget(self.page1)
        self.frame_layout.addWidget(self.page2)


class Page(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, frame_layout, parent=None):
        super(Page, self).__init__(parent)

        print(self.width(), self.height())
        self.frame_layout = frame_layout

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.frame_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191)")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.label.setText(text)
        self.frame_layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.frame_layout)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.showMaximized()
        print(self.width(), self.height())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is a bit obscure, as your code is. For instance, the `Xyz` widget does not contain anything, its `page1` and `page2` widgets are just added to a stacked layout that is not set to any widget (that's why you see the first page as a separate window, I'll eventually explain why the second does not). Then you are using the `frame_layout` argument to create `Page` instances, you set it as an instance attribute but then overwrite it just after that. Can you please clarify what should be the widget structure?

Comment: @musicamante, well what I want to have is a button as defined in class ```Abc```, on clicking that button I should be redirected to ```Xyz``` class which now contains multiple pages (in this case "Page 1" and "Page 2"). Then, I want a functionality to navigate between those pages.

Comment: Is it necessary to have Xyz? From what I can see, it doesn't seem to be "specialized" in any way, so your structure looks a bit too complicated than it could be: can't you just use a single QStackedWidget, directly add those two pages to it, then just add functions to switch between them (index 1 and 2), ignoring the first page.

Comment: @musicamante, well yes it is absolutely necessary to have Xyz. Actually, my actaul project contains over 50 pages and I have created the project as you are suggesting but it gives an annoying effect when I launch the application. It looks as if the pages are loading one over the other. That's why I created a class Xyz with ```QStackedLayout``` to avoid that.

Comment: *One* of the issues you're facing doesn't depend on having `Xyz`, but due to the fact that you didn't set the layout for that widget (it actually does *nothing* at all), so all pages are actually shown as stand alone top level windows. Is the start page (the one with the button) going to be shown again at any time, or only at start?

Comment: @musicamante, the start page will only be shown once at the start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219061/discussion-between-the-dark-lord-and-musicamante).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not setting the QStackedLayout for the `Xyz` widget, the result is that all pages will actually appear as top level windows.

When a widget is added to a layout, it takes ownership of it; if the layout is already set to a widget, then the widget that was added to the layout becomes reparented to the other. The same happens if you set the layout *afterwards*.

Why does it show the first page as a separate window? And why doesn't it show the second?
When a new widget is created without a parent, it becomes a top level window; when a widget is added to a *new* stacked layout, Qt automatically tries to show it; you didn't set the layout to anything (which would reparent it as explained before), and the result is that the first page is shown as a standalone window.

Now, since the first "screen" is going to be shown only the first time, you can set that widget as the central widget, and then set a Xyz instance (which is actually a QStackedWidget subclass) as a *new* central widget.

Note that you don't need to use QWidget to add a QFrame if that's the only parent widget shown: you can just subclass QFrame.

This is a much simpler and cleaner version of your code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.startPage = Abc()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.startPage)

        self.startPage.startRequest.connect(self.buildPages)

    def buildPages(self):
        self.pages = Xyz()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.pages)


class Abc(QtGui.QFrame):
    startRequest = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Abc, self).__init__(parent)
        
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Click me!')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startRequest)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)


class Xyz(QtGui.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Xyz, self).__init__(parent)

        self.page1 = Page("Page 1")
        self.page2 = Page("Page 2")
        self.addWidget(self.page1)
        self.addWidget(self.page2)

        self.page1.switchRequest.connect(lambda: self.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.page2.switchRequest.connect(lambda: self.setCurrentIndex(0))


class Page(QtGui.QFrame):
    switchRequest = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Page, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        # set the background only for QFrame subclasses (which also includes 
        # QLabel), this prevents setting the background for other classes, 
        # such as the push button
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QFrame {
                background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191)
            }
        ''')
        # when adding a widget to a layout, the layout tries to automatically 
        # make it as big as possible (based on the widget's sizeHint); so you
        # should not use the alignment argument for layout.addWidget(), but for 
        # the label instead
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(text, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.switchButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Switch')
        layout.addWidget(self.switchButton)
        self.switchButton.clicked.connect(self.switchRequest)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. But still can't understand the whole ownership concept. Looks like PyQt is not as easy as I thought it is. But thanks a lot, you have solved my problem.

Comment: @thedarklord I suggest you to carefully study the documentation (I know, it's very long and demanding, but believe me, it's worth it). The basic concept is that `QObject` descendants (including **all** QWidget subclasses) can have *only one* parent (or none at all!); when you read something like "x takes ownership of y" in the documentation, it usually means that `x` becomes the [parent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#parent) of `y`. Simply speaking, when you add widgetY to a layout that is set on widgetX, widgetX becomes the parent of widgetY. But that's a bit more complex for QWidgets.

Comment: I know that the docs are a bit obscure about it (especially the whole "the layout takes ownership"). Consider that a QWidget that has no *QWidget* parent, by default is always shown as a top level widget (this also happens if you add the widget to a layout that is not [yet] set to another widget). If you want to add a widget as a child of another one, you either initialize it with that parent widget argument, manually use [`setParent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent), or add it to a layout that sooner or later is set to the parent, otherwise it will be a top level window.

Comment: While the docs are C++ oriented, it also works for python too: 99% of times the arguments and returned values are the same for PyQt (just remember, `void` means that the function returns `None`). There is the [official PyQt documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/), but it's not always comprehensive nor complete; by the way, you can use it as a reference for specialized functions that are only available on PyQt.

Comment: @thedarklord what do you mean? Giving a size to what?

Comment: actually I was trying to get the size of this button (it's height and width), but it gave me 640x480. Why is that? I can clearly see that the button size is way smaller than this size. How can I get the correct size?

Comment: *When* are you looking for the size? If you're doing it before the window is actually shown (or even before adding it to the layout), that's perfectly normal: all QWidgets have a default size of 640x480 right after they're created.

Comment: Actually, I saw [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214144/trouble-in-retrieving-window-size-and-widget-size) post. And was playing with his code for learning purposes. I tried a few things but couldn't solve the problem. then I tried to get size of the Switch button and couldn't get it. I actually used ```self.switchButton.size()``` at the end of the class. So, I was doing it after adding it to the layout.

Comment: If by "at the end of the class" you mean at the end of the `__init__`, it's still the same: until widgets are mapped the first time they're shown, their size will always be 640x480, unless some size restriction is applied. If you want to get their "final" size, you have to get it within the `resizeEvent()` or `showEvent()`.