# Trouble in retrieving window size and widget size

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

Here is the code for a camera surveillance system. In the `configuration_page.py` file I'm getting the size of the window as **100x30** despite using `self.showMaximized()` and `resizeEvent()`. The widgets present in it are also showing the size as **640x480**. I'm particularly interested in retrieving the size of a widget named `self.mid_frame` in **CameraDisplay** class present in `config.py` file.

Earlier I was facing the same issue in `dashboard.py` file but I found a workaround by explicitly passing width and height in that case. But this time I'm stuck because I need to get the size of the widget named `self.mid_frame`. I don't understand why even **resizeEvent** is showing the wrong size.

main.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from threading import Thread, RLock, Lock
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import cv2
import imutils
from dashboard import *
from configuration_page import *
from global_widgets import *


class CameraWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Independent camera feed
    Uses threading to grab IP camera frames in the background

    @param width - Width of the video frame
    @param height - Height of the video frame
    @param stream_link - IP/RTSP/Webcam link
    @param aspect_ratio - Whether to maintain frame aspect ratio or force into fraame
    """

    def __init__(self, stream_link=0, stacked_widget=None, width=0, height=0, btn_text=None, idx=None, aspect_ratio=False, parent=None, deque_size=1):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize deque used to store frames read from the stream
        self.deque = deque(maxlen=deque_size)
        
        self.maintain_aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio
        self.camera_stream_link = stream_link
        self.stacked_widget = stacked_widget
        self.idx = idx

        # Flag to check if camera is valid/working
        self.online = False
        self.capture = None

        self.video_frame = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.video_frame_1 = QtGui.QLabel()

        self.load_network_stream()

        # Start background frame grabbing
        self.get_frame_thread = Thread(target=self.get_frame, args=())
        self.get_frame_thread.daemon = True
        self.get_frame_thread.start()

        # Periodically set video frame to display
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.set_frame)
        self.timer.start(.5)

        print('Started camera: {}'.format(self.camera_stream_link))

    def load_network_stream(self):
        """Verifies stream link and open new stream if valid"""

        def load_network_stream_thread():
            if self.verify_network_stream(self.camera_stream_link):
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_stream_link)
                self.online = True
        self.load_stream_thread = Thread(target=load_network_stream_thread, args=())
        self.load_stream_thread.daemon = True
        self.load_stream_thread.start()

    def verify_network_stream(self, link):
        """Attempts to receive a frame from given link"""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False
        cap.release()
        return True

    def get_frame(self):
        """Reads frame, resizes, and converts image to pixmap"""

        while True:
            try:
                if self.capture.isOpened() and self.online:
                    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
                    status, frame = self.capture.read()

                    if status:
                        self.deque.append(frame)
                    else:
                        self.capture.release()
                        self.online = False
                else:
                    # Attempt to reconnect
                    print('attempting to reconnect', self.camera_stream_link)
                    self.load_network_stream()
                    self.spin(2)
                self.spin(.001)
                
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def spin(self, seconds):
        """Pause for set amount of seconds, replaces time.sleep so program doesnt stall"""

        time_end = time.time() + seconds
        while time.time() < time_end:
            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def set_frame(self):
        """Sets pixmap image to video frame"""

        if not self.online:
            self.spin(1)
            return

        if self.deque and self.online:
            # Grab latest frame
            frame = self.deque[-1]
            frame_1 = self.deque[-1]

            # Display frames on dashboard and configuration pages
            # Frame for dashboard
            # Keep frame aspect ratio
            if self.maintain_aspect_ratio:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=self.screen_width)
            # Force resize
            else:
                self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
                self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = self.frame.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w

            # Frame for configuration page-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                # print('2: ', self.screen_width_1, self.screen_height_1)
                self.frame_1 = cv2.resize(frame_1, (self.screen_width_1, self.screen_height_1))
                self.frame_1 = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h_1, w_1, ch_1 = self.frame_1.shape
                bytesPerLine_1 = ch_1 * w_1

            # Convert to pixmap and set to video frame
            self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
            self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)

            self.img_1 = QtGui.QImage(self.frame_1, w_1, h_1, bytesPerLine_1, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.pix_1 = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img_1)                                             
            self.video_frame_1.setPixmap(self.pix_1)

    def set_frame_params(self, width, height, btn_text=None, idx=0):
        self.screen_width = width
        self.screen_height = height
        self.btn_text = btn_text
        self.idx = idx

    def set_frame_params_1(self, width, height):
        self.screen_width_1 = width
        self.screen_height_1 = height

    def get_video_display_frame(self):
        self.video_display_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.video_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.video_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.btn_text)
        self.video_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(128, 159, 255);")
        self.video_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        # self.video_frame = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.video_frame.setScaledContents(True)
        self.video_layout.addWidget(self.video_btn)
        self.video_layout.addWidget(self.video_frame)
        self.video_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.video_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.video_display_frame.setLayout(self.video_layout)

        return self.video_display_frame

    def get_video_frame(self):
        self.video_frame_1.setScaledContents(True)
        return self.video_frame_1

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        GlobalObject().dispatchEvent("hello", args=(self.idx,))
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1)


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.stacked_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.cam1 = CameraWidget(camera1, self.stacked_widget, idx=1)

        widget_1 = DashBoard(self.cam1, self.stacked_widget)
        widget_2 = ZoneConfig(self.cam1, self.stacked_widget)

        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(widget_1)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(widget_2)

        self.showMaximized()
        

camera1 = '../streams/Fog.avi'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))
    # app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))

    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

dashboard.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from global_widgets import *


class DashBoard(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, cam1, stacked_widget, parent=None):
        super(DashBoard, self).__init__(parent)

        self.showMaximized()

        self.screen_width = self.width()
        self.screen_height = self.height()

        self.stacked_widget = stacked_widget

        # Layouts and frames
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        top_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        top_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")
        mid_frame = QtGui.QFrame()   
        mid_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")

        layout.addWidget(top_frame, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QHLine())
        layout.addWidget(mid_frame, 20)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        # Top frame
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Dashboard')
        label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 20))

        top_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        top_layout.addWidget(label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        top_layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        top_frame.setLayout(top_layout)

        # Middle frame
        self.mid_layout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()

        # Create camera widgets
        print('Creating Camera Widgets...')

        cam_widget = Cam1(cam1, self.screen_width, self.screen_height, self)
        self.mid_layout.addWidget(cam_widget)
        self.mid_layout.setCurrentWidget(cam_widget)
        mid_frame.setLayout(self.mid_layout)  


class Cam1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, cam1, screen_width, screen_height, parent=None):
        super(Cam1, self).__init__(parent)

        cam1.set_frame_params(screen_width, screen_height, 'VIDS 01', 1)

        # Add widgets to layout
        print('Adding widgets to layout...')
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(cam1.get_video_display_frame(),0,0,1,1)
        layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

configuration_page.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from global_widgets import *
from ui_main import *


class ZoneConfig(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, cam1, stacked_widget, parent=None):
        super(ZoneConfig, self).__init__(parent)
        
        GlobalObject().addEventListener("hello", self.set_cam)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.frame_layout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()
        # self.setLayout(self.frame_layout)

        self.screen_width = self.width()
        self.screen_height = self.height()

        cam_widget_1 = CameraDisplay(cam1, 1, self.frame_layout, stacked_widget, self)

        self.frame_layout.addWidget(cam_widget_1)

        self.frame.setLayout(self.frame_layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def set_cam(self, index):
        if index == 1:
            self.frame_layout.setCurrentIndex(0)


class CameraDisplay(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, cam, idx, frame_layout, stacked_widget, parent=None):
        super(CameraDisplay, self).__init__(parent)

        self.showMaximized()

        self.screen_width = self.width()
        self.screen_height = self.height()
        self.frame_layout = frame_layout
        self.stacked_widget = stacked_widget    

        print('size: ', self.screen_width, self.screen_height)

        # Layouts and frames
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        top_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        top_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")
        self.mid_frame = QtGui.QFrame()                                           ## Size of this frame is needed
        self.mid_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")
        btm_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        btm_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")
        
        # Top frame
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Configuration')
        label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 20))

        top_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        top_layout.addWidget(label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        top_layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        top_frame.setLayout(top_layout)

        # Middle frame
        mid_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        # Create camera widgets
        print('Creating Camera Widgets...')
        mid_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.video_frame = cam.get_video_frame()
        mid_layout.addWidget(self.video_frame)
        mid_layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        self.mid_frame.setLayout(mid_layout)

        # Bottom frame
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Dashboard')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.goMainWindow)

        btm_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        btm_layout.addStretch()
        btm_layout.addWidget(btn)
        btm_layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        btm_frame.setLayout(btm_layout)

        layout.addWidget(top_frame, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QHLine())
        layout.addWidget(self.mid_frame, 50)
        layout.addWidget(QHLine())
        layout.addWidget(btm_frame, 1)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        # self.showMaximized()

        cam.set_frame_params_1(self.mid_frame.width(), self.mid_frame.height()-10)      ## here I want the size

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

    def goMainWindow(self):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

**I think the problem is only in `configuration_page.py` file but I'm pasting entire code in case anyone wants to go throught the entire logic.**

Comment: All widgets have a default 640x480 size until they are mapped (and layed out, if layout managers are used) the first time they are shown, which happens *after* calling `show()`. Unfortunately your code is too extensive to understand where/when/why you need those sizes. In any case, you can only get the actual size of widgets only *after* they've been shown and all layouts have completed their size computations.

Comment: @musicamante, I need the size in ```config.py``` file just above the resizeEvent() in the ```CameraDisplay``` class. I have attached other files just for reference. Should I reduce the code further?

Comment: As said, all widgets have a default 640x480 size until they are finally mapped on the screen for the first time. Since your issue seems to be only related to widgets (and everything else, including the image management parts, are not required, I suggest you to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) based on your existing code. If you still have issues, edit this question and provide *that* example.

Comment: @musicamante I have reduced the length of the code. Please have a look!

Comment: Please, read the link and follow its directions. Minimal means that it should **only** include code relevant to the issue (your code still includes image load and management parts which are unnecessary), reproducible means that we *must* be able to copy, paste and run it (some classes are missing, such as `GlobalObject`). In any case, I already told you that *ALL* widgets have a 640x480 size until they are finally mapped on the screen. Calling `showMaximized` does *not* show and resize the widget immediately, if you want to get the final correct size, you have to do that *afterwards*.

Comment: You can do it in the `resizeEvent`, but you cannot rely on its "first" result, so if you need that values you have to use signals/slot to notify each size change. Note that if you want to know the *screen* size, you certainly should *not* get the size of a maximized window (especially if you use the values returned while you're still in the `__init__`). Use [`QApplication.primaryScreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your code.

```
def event(self, e):
    if e.type() in (QEvent.Show, QEvent.Resize):
        widget_w = self.mid_frame.frameGeometry().width()
        widget_h = self.mid_frame.frameGeometry().height()
        screen_w = self.width()
        screen_h = self.height()

        # For "debugging" purposes:
        print("Widget - width: %s height: %s" % (widget_w, widget_h)
        print("screen - width: %s height: %s" % (screen_w, screen_h)
       
        return ((widget_w, widget_h), (screen_w, screen_h))

        #return {"widget": {"width": widget_w, "height": widget_h}, "screen": {"width": screen_w, "height": screen_h}}
```